# Plain text email padding with PHP

Tags: php, string, codeigniter, plaintext

I am building a plain text email with Codeigniter but I want to pad some headings:

At the moment they are coming out like:

```
Client : ABC Structures Ltd
Contact : Jeoff Black
Ticket ID : 83738
```

But I really want it like this:

```
Client     : ABC Structures Ltd
Contact    : Jeoff Black
Ticket ID  : 83738
```

I tried using str_pad() but it doesn't seem to work. I tried using `" "` and even `chr(32)` but it just doesn't seem to do anything. If I pad it with a normal character like - it works fine, but I just want spaces.

I tried just manually spacing the template, but the spaces are removed.

So, I've tried:

```
<?php echo str_pad("Client", 15);?>: <?php echo $client_name; ?>
```

And even

```
Client      : <?php echo $client_name; ?>
```

Its not even that important, I'm just determined to resolve it... I'm guessing I need some sort of unicode character in there...? Not sure how to output it...

Thanks.

Comment: like with every html page if you have more than one space in a row it acts like one space. To accommodate this use `&nbsp;` for a non breaking space or tab/large spaces are: `&thinsp;`, `&ensp;` and `&emsp;`

Comment: tabs should work just fine `\t`

Comment: Strange that `" "` wouldn't work; it's even the default. Could it be that you applied `trim()` or something to the padded string?

Comment: maybe its not really being sent as plain txt, but html - check the headers. regardless i would solve this with html email and a table. Theres not much against html email anymore

Comment: @Class I tried `&nbsp;` but thats a HTML entity, so that'd never work in a PLAINTEXT email, surely?

Comment: @Dagon Tabs don't work, as some strings are longer than others, and then the longer strings are tabbed more than the shorter strings. And its definitely plain text

Comment: @lxg I definitely have no trim() in there... I thought it was odd too. I was expecting spaces to be translated as spaces in plain text...

Comment: ok, i would still just use an html table, plain text is not capable of formatting as well.

Comment: Well there is that option. But I like to know why things don't work in addition to using a work around... ACTUALLY, a table wouldn't render correctly anyway in plain text...? It would output the tags as text...

Comment: you send html email, not plain text email. I dont think its a work around, if you want\need formatting, use  the right language for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was down to me having HTML content, rather than plain text. Doh.

Answer (score 0):

Try str_repeat:

```
$string = "Client";
$width = 20;
$padded = $string . str_repeat(" ", $width - strlen($string));
echo "$padded:";
```

Output:

```
Client              :
```

Maybe insert a fallback if `$width - strlen($string)` < 0.

Comment: This doesn't work also. I'm just going to create a plain text doc to see if it works... Might be codeigniter mucking about...

Comment: Yeah, I thought so, after reading all the comments on the question. Sorry.